# Can a Lookup list field point to web property bag?

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, content-query-web-part, caml, property-bag

In my subwebs I have a 1 row list called "Details" that contains various bits of data that are meant to be web-level metadata. Image field, AssignedTo field, couple of string columns, etc.

On top of that at the root level I have a Content Query Web Part that grabs all subweb lists of type Details and displays this metadata in a grid.

What I would like to do is add a column to this list that returns the Title and Url of the site, however I don't want to duplicate data by creating a field to store it. I just want to return data that's already available at the web level.

Does anyone know if it's possible to add a Lookup column (or calculated) that will lookup a property in the web property bag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot create a lookup field against a web property.

If your skills in JS and Display Templates are up for it, you might already have access to web title and url in the `ctx` object.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_quick_reads/archive/2013/09/03/3588171.aspx

Comment: By the way, it looks like what you really want to accomplish is to create some sort of site directory grabbing title, url, and some additional metadata. You might want to consider asking a question here on how to approach that. You might find there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it's appreciated. In essence, yes, it's a site directory. We're already grabbing details from all subsite Details lists via a CQWP, so I thought if we could tie Url and Title into that directly, we could save a REST or CSOM call. One of the reasons for going with a list vs. stuffing the web property bag is to use the built-in form editing capabilities of a list.

Comment: Here's something I've done in similar situations, Jim: Make the site home page a custom content type (derived from web part page) and put your properties in there.